# The variable 'NaN' might be used before it is defined

Tags: matlab

I never had any problems with this, today when I tried to create a custom function in Matlab I got a very weird error that never occured before:

Basically when I try to initialize the NaN with dimensions, I keep getting:

The variable 'NaN' might be used before it is defined

See screenshot:
[image]

What has happened? Where is this coming from?

Comment: Pictures of code are not nearly as useful as the actual code.  Can you copy & paste the actual code into the question

Comment: Nope, I restarted Matlab and I have nothing in the workspace. When I run the function I actually get the error: Undefined function or variable 'NaN'.

Comment: What is weird also is that when I remove lines 7-9 then there is no issue

Comment: Nothing is wrong.  It seems you are using NaN incorrectly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is fine as you are using the function NaN to create a matrix of NaN.

```
 rmatrix = NaN(M,M)
```

This line is not:

```
indicesX = NaN(M*M,:);
```

This is treating NaN as a variable that you did not previous define ... hence the error.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a million! How did you find this out?

Comment: @AnderBiguri ..lol.  That is good way to put it.   John, I am not sure what you intended to happen when trying to create the var `indicesx` but if you could explain I could probably correct the syntax

Comment: Just to initialize a matrix of NaN(k,1) where k = M*M. I guess I forgot the 1... and put the :

Comment: Yep, that would do it.  Just replace `:` with 1 and you will get what you wanted.

Comment: Should take a break, missed the : totally